# jblough library not supporting UniJIS-UCS2-HW-H encoding

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I am using jblough library https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library for viewing pdf. But its not showing japaneese characters inside the pdf. I think UniJIS-UCS2-HW-H cmap not included . Whether this is reason for the issue ? how can i overcome this ?